How to test association between one dependent categorical variable and several independent categorical variables?
I have a dataset with bus trips. I want to test whether there is a correlation between the bus trip type and other variables: It looks like that (with 250k rows)



Trip type
land use
Closest POI




fast
industrial
Restaurant


slow
parks
University


super slow
residential
Hotel



Can I make a regression model to predict trip type based on the other columns? How to do that?

About checking the correlation between categorical variables
If you just want to check if there is an association between them, you can try verifying the chi-square, which is a measure of association between qualitative variables.
About using regression
You are dealing with a classification problem precisely because the dependent (or target) variable is categorical. The possible regression in this case would be logistic regression, and even then you would need to use it in combination with some multiclass classification technique (search for the one versus one and one versus rest techniques), as it is only capable of distinguishing between two classes. It seems that the variable ‘Trip type’ has more than two classes.
In any case, I recommend you search for decision trees, random forests, and catboost. These are three models that should work in your case.
